# Making a call to a local server, smashing two localhost's together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I'm not sure how to better word this, I am trying to call a login route on my express server to use with my Vue 3 app. They are running on different servers, one on port 5500 (express) and 5173 (vue). In my Vue Login component, I call a function which uses the authStore to contact the express server, where the login logic is being handled. Here is the relevant code:

```js
//authStore.js

import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("authStore", {
  state: () => ({
    token: null,
  }),
  actions: {
    async loginUser(formData) {
        console.log(formData)
      try {
        const headers = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: formData,
          }
          console.log(headers)
        const res = await fetch("127.0.0.1:5500/apiv1/login", headers);
        console.log(res)
        if (res.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          this.token = data.token;
          console.log(data.token)
        } else {
          console.log("Unable to login.");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
});
```

```js
//server.js (Express)
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pool = require("./sql_db");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongo = require("./mongo_db");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;
//other routes that do work, omitted.
async function querySql(statement, values) {
  const query = await pool.query(statement, values);
  const results = query.rows;
  return results;
}

app.post("/apiv1/login", async (req, res) => {
  //Get the login creds from the request

  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    //Query the database, similar to above, just searching a different table
    const loginQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1;';
    const queryRes = await querySql(loginQuery, [username]);
    const user = queryRes[0];


    //if it doesn't return a user, send 404 (Not Found)
    if (!user) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }

    const storedPass = user.password;

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, storedPass);

    // if passwords don't match, send 403 (Unauthorised)
    if (!validPassword) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }

    jwt.sign({ user: user.id }, "secretkey", (err, token) => {
      res.json({
        token,
      });
    });
    // All good, send 200 (Success)
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    //Something else isn't working, log the error and send 500 (internal server error)
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

```js
//Login.vue
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/authStore';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const route = useRouter();

const username = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const authStore = useAuthStore();

function login() {
  const formData = {
    username: username.value, 
    password: password.value
  }
  if(authStore.loginUser(formData)){
    route.push({path: '/', replace: true})
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-50">
    <h4>some image here</h4>
    <form @submit.prevent="login()">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text">Username: </span>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input v-model="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingUsernameInput"
            placeholder="Username">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text">Password: </span>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <input v-model="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPasswordInput"
            placeholder="Username">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row g-3">
        <button class="col btn btn-success form-control mx-1">Login</button>
        <button class="col btn btn-danger form-control mx-1">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here is the console output I get, note the URL in the response object:
[image]

SQL db, showing the user exists (its all dummy data, passwords are "password" hashed w/bcrypt)
[image]

Comment: Your service is returning `404`, but seems to have been configured to do so if the database lookup of users does not return data. You should be able to use your debugger to inspect what's returned from the database to ensure it matches your expectations. Nobody here can opine if that is truly the issue, since you haven't provided your code as a [mre] (which would be significantly less verbose and include the `querySql()` method's definition, at the very least).

Comment: added in the `querySql()` method. I'm aware its returning 404, and I know WHY its returning 404, I don't understand why its making the request URL "http://localhost:5137/127.0.0.1:5500/apiv1/login"

Comment: Ah, my mistake - apologies! I understand the issue now.